# Would it be pathetic to borrow an iOS / Android device from someone just to get the Not a Cherry / Bugdroid hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014, winter-bash

I only have an Android device, and got the Bugdroid hat easily. Neither my wife nor I have an iOS device.

Would it be too pathetic / embarrassing to ask my brother to borrow his iPad,  or ask my father to borrow his iPhone, just to install the iOS app and get the Not a Cherry hat?

What would I say? Can I borrow your device in order to install an app,  so that I can win a virtual hat?

Disclaimer, this question was shamelessly used to get the On the Road hat.

Comment: I got two hats for posting this, though not the hat I expected.

Comment: As a completely unbiased third party, I'm in favor of this.

Comment: Would it be pathetic to VTC this, edit it, and VTRO just to get the breaking bad hat?

Comment: I installed a Android VM on my windows machine and used the app from there. Does that count as cheating?-)

Comment: @ClausJørgensen that's resourceful :) If I had a Mac I could have installed the app on the iPhone simulator, but I don't.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, since the iOS simulator require x86/x86_64 builds.

Comment: I didn't even get any hat for browsing this site on  Android, but that may be because I don't see why I should have to download an app to see a Web page.

Answer (score 13):

No, it's not pathetic. I'd say it's "sad" at best. Maybe "crazy."

*"Pathetic"* would be *buying* an iOS or Android device just to get the hat.

Comment: I agree that buying a device would be worse, but that would make buying a device "crazy", since "crazy" is more extreme than "pathetic".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's pathetic. It's just a virtual Internet hat.

But if you can convince someone without making a fool of yourself... Go for it!

Comment: I'm sure I can convince them, but I'd probably be too embarrassed to do it.