# When asking from Android app, showing new question fails

Tags: support, bug, android-app

I've only used the app to post a few times, but when I do this always happens: I submit the question, the app seems to try to take me to my new question, and I get a failure message with a "retry" button, which doesn't change anything. However, my question really was posted, as confirmed in a browser on a computer.

Is this normal? (Maybe my connection is dicey and the timing is unforgiving?) The first time it happened I was alarmed because I thought I'd lost my work.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: @ShadowWizard if the cause of my problem was network burps then that would be a dupe. I don't know if it actually was. I've posted from the app three times recently and this happened each time. In each of those cases I didn't notice any other network problems -- while sitting in one place I accessed the site, composed and sent a post, and got this error. This doesn't *rule out* network glitches; different operations require different degrees of connectivity and maybe that happened here (e.g. you can get mail but not be able to stream video sometimes). Don't know; saw no other network errors.

Comment: @ShadowWizard also, different error message, though it could be the same underlying cause.

Comment: True, that's why I didn't voted to close just mentioned it's possibly dupe. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard yup, understood.  Thanks for pointing out the other question to me.