# How much do hats increase positive behaviors compared to the rest of the year?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, data-analysis

Most of the hats are designed to reward positive behaviors, behaviors that benefit the sites -- reviewing, editing, answering questions (well), participating on meta, and so on.  (The others aren't designed to reward *negative* behaviors; rather, some of them are just intentionally quirky.)  I have two questions, which I hope someone at SE can answer:

1. How much do hats increase these activities?  Are lots more people doing a lot more of these things, or is it really just a few die-hard hatters?  How big is the activity spike?  Obviously this can't be answered until the end of the season, though it could be answered about *last* year's hats, which leads to...
2. Do those changes endure?  To what extent do people who increase some positive activity for the hats form a habit and keep doing it?  Do the bursts of edits, for example, during hat season lead to those people doing more editing in the months after the hats get put away?  Or are people only doing things for the hats?  Can we quantify this?

I suspect that SE discusses questions like these internally, and y'all have a couple of excellent data scientists now, so can you share what you learn about headwear-induced behavior modification?

A couple WinterBashes ago I asked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246007/how-do-hats-modify-users-behavior) about how hats modified users' behavior during (that year's) hat season.  In this question I'm asking about comparisons to non-hat season and enduring effects.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246007/how-do-hats-modify-users-behavior

Comment: @random I forgot about that.  But this question is different; see my edit.

Comment: April fools is my favourite festival. All dumb behaviours are forgiven that day. It's a proof that how broadminded people can be.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's hard to measure "positive behaviors", since that's a subjective criteria, and even if it wasn't, it would be hard to collect the data. What you can measure is the total activity (good or bad) in a given site.

Looking at Site Analytics, you can compare the activity in a site during hat season and off season. I looked at the [Site Analytics of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics) and found that traffic goes down around hat season, which is not surprising given the holidays.

I think that one of the motivations for Winter Bash (besides the great fun it is) was to increase traffic in a time when it goes down.

Here are some numbers. I looked at the number of posts in each year between Oct-1 and Apr-1 of the next year (i.e. several months before and after the holidays).

Taking the worst and best days in each of these 6 month periods, we get:

```
period          lowest # of posts   highest # of posts  % of low # of posts
                                                        from high # of posts

2015-2016       8489 (12/25)        25115 (2/25)        33.8  \
2014-2015       8475 (1/1)          23610 (3/25)        35.9   \ the Winter Bash
2013-2014       9808 (12/25)        27304 (2/26)        35.9   / years
2012-2013       8068 (12/23)        24174 (3/20)        33.4  /

2011-2012       4644 (12/25)        18143 (2/23)        25.6  \
2010-2011       3444 (12/25)        14144 (3/22)        24.3   \ the pre Winter Bash
2009-2010       2163 (12/25)        8121 (3/3)          26.6   / years
2008-2009       936 (12/25)         4784 (10/2)         19.5  /
```

While this is a very unscientific analysis (I should have probably calculated weekly or monthly averages instead of comparing the min and max values, but I don't have time for that), it still seems to indicate that the end of years having Winter Bah (2012-2015) had a smaller activity loss compared to the early years that didn't have Winter Bash (2008-2011).

This seems to indicate that hats increase activity on Stack Overflow, and offset some of the slowdown of the holidays season.

Some of the graphs from which I took these numbers :

[image: 2008-2009]
[image: 2009-2010]
[image: 2010-2011]
[image: 2015-2016]

BTW, it would be interesting to run the same comparison on the number of votes and the number of visits, but I don't have the time.

Comment: Thanks for this analysis!  By "positive activity" I didn't mean something arbitrary; as I understand it, SE designs the hats to encourage certain behaviors that they see as positive.  It's those behaviors, which they can specify and we can somewhat infer, that I'm asking about.  That's a good point about one goal being to just plain increase traffic, though -- hadn't thought of that, and as you say, we can measure that.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Well, some of the hats, for example, encourage posting more questions, answers and comments. You can measure an increase in the number of posted questions, answers and comments, but measuring whether such an increase is an increase in "positive activity" is much harder, since analyzing the quality of the posts and comments is difficult and often subjective.