# Doesn't the Winter Bash hat thing promote bad questions and/or answers?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

Winter Bash is fun, but with some of the hat rules, doesn't it encourage people to put up superfluous posts? For example, one hat requiring

> Posting a new question when the UTC minutes equal 00, 15, or 30

Encourages people to post a question even if the don't really have one for the sake of getting a hat.

Comment: Wow. Classy. It's almost like you can trade downvotes for hats

Comment: This smells like a duplicate of something.

Comment: You should have posted this question "when the UTC minutes equal 00, 15, or 30"... perhaps that would have swayed you opinion. ;)

Comment: @Werner https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7NcG.png

Comment: I just found this related post today. I wouldn't say it's a duplicate of mine, as it's a different angle, but this may be what @Mast was thinking of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246007/how-do-hats-modify-users-behavior/246018#246018

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Almost all hats have an [implicit quality requirement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/1438). If a post doesn't get any upvotes, there's a good chance the author won't get a hat.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the answer is that everyone always has questions and they should just make sure they post thoughtful, high quality questions to get the hats. If the questions aren't quality, they will be discouraged by down voting.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stopping anyone writing a **good** question and waiting until the appropriate time before clicking <kbd>Post Your Question</kbd> in order get "The Hatter" hat.

Comment: The point is not that the hat *forces* bad behavior, yes, it's obviously possible to get the had *without* behaving badly.  The question is if it will encourage some number of people to behave badly, even if some don't.