# I'd like all Winter bash hats to be "secret hats"... why not?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, secret-hats

All Winter bash hats should be secret.

What do you think, do we need Regular Hats? Regular hats are such when you know exactly what to do to earn from the very beginning. "Regular hats" give no intrigue, it is the same as convincing to vote to get reward, to do something you already know how.

Of course discussion like this [Winter Bash 2021 Hat List 😷 🎓](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372999/347648) are useful because very secret secrets can remain secret forever.

Comment: This seems more of a [feature-request]?

Comment: @bobble It is just a discussion, interesting what everyone thinks

Comment: If you don't look at the explanation for each hat, all hats are secret hats.

Comment: @Laurel Right. Then why there are secret and regular hats at all.... Of course I will look

Comment: Because there *are* people who appreciate the difference?

Comment: All hats being secret hats make them non special

Answer (score 6):

I always thought of hats as 'temporary badges'. The exact criteria for badges are known, and that doesn't cause a problem either; at least usually [exceptions noted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362020/295232) – that was caused by a user thought to be hunting for Electorate badges.

With secret-only hats, we'd 1) raise the barriers to entry, contrary to the Winter Bash philosophy 2) encourage people to experiment even more, which is [not necessarily a good idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374074/295232).

If *you* want the hat triggers to be secret, you can probably block the hat descriptions with an uBlock-compatible ad-blocker or a userscript. Or perhaps completely opt-out from Winter Bash?

Answer (score 5):

I like Glorfindel's last paragraph in his answer:

> "If you want the hat triggers to be secret, you can probably block the hat descriptions with an uBlock-compatible ad-blocker or a userscript. Or perhaps completely opt-out from Winter Bash?"

But I'll take that even one step further and just say that if you want all secrets to be secret to you, then you can simply not look up their triggers (i.e., don't go to the "Winter Bash Hat List" post on Meta.SE, and don't click on any hat descriptions on the Winter Bash website. These two things don't even require you to use an ad-blocker or userscript.

If you want all hats to be secret for *other* people, then you've come to the right place to try to get consensus on that since this is the site where the community would express their opinions in favor (or not in favor) of your proposal, and where you'd get the best opportunity to convince SE to make the change. **My opinion on the issue is that we should keep it the way it is, where roughly 50% of the hats are secret and 50% are not.**

Comment: Yep, of course I know how to make all hats secret to me only and this is not what I asked about. Your last paragraph describes it correctly and I hope I asked this in the right place. Also I'm rather curious about what is behind... Will 100% of secret hats really encourage people to experiment more than 50% of secret hats?

Comment: People like to collect everything, even temporary things like these hats. And me too. And I am not against it, I thought secret hats have higher collection value than non-secret hats.